# Правильная задержка во время выполнения Java кода

Tags: java, android, время

Я решил написать свою игру на `java` (текстовый квест). По задумке когда игра дает вам право выбора(три кнопки с разными вариантами), то после нажатия кнопки должны моментально исчезнуть и через 1 секунду появиться текст, через еще 2 секунды еще один кусок текста (и так далее). То есть создать эффект появления текста. Я попробовал сделать это таким образом:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btn2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//скрываем кнопки
        btn3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        try {
            Tread.sleep(1000)
        } catch(InterruptedException e){

        }

        textofgamestory1.setText(R.string.chapter1part1text2gv1);//меняем текст
        textofgamestory1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//делаем его видимым

        try {
            Tread.sleep(1000)
        } catch(InterruptedException e){

        }

        textofgamestory2.setText(R.string.chapter1part1text3gv1);
        textofgamestory2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

но, при проверки этого кода, при нажатии на кнопку, кнопки не исчезали сразу, а ждали 1 секунду а потом исчезали вмести с появлением самого текста целиком, а это не то что мне нужно. 
Надеюсь кто нибудь знает как правильно сделать такую задержку, заранее спасибо.

Comment: View.postDelayed(Runnable, long) https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/148-urok-85-esche-neskolko-sposobov-vypolnenija-koda-v-ui-potoke.html

Answer (score 4):

1. Не используйте `Tread.sleep` в главном потоке при программировании под Андроид. Странно, что система не убила Ваше приложение. Никакие паузы тут недопустимы.
2. Для решения Вашей проблемы простейший метод (без сторонних библиотек):

   ```
   //поле класса активности / фрагмента
   Handler h;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       h = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
       ...
   }

   //далее в пределах метода (onClick, например)
   Runnable r = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           // Что нужно сделать после задержки, Ваш код
       }
   }; 
   h.postDelayed(r, 1000); //с задержкой 1000 миллисекунд

   //отписаться надо не забыть!
   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
       super.onPause();
   }
   ```

Comment: И не забудь отписаться от хэндлера, иначе можно получить утечку памяти.

`@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}`

Comment: @ШамильАслануков спасибо, забыл об этом написать) Ответ обновил)